# Limit Search to Product Pages only unless I'm on Blogpage or Blogposts

Tags: php, functions, search

I'm using the following code to limit my search to products only (searching in the product archive).

```
// Only show products in the front-end search results
add_filter('pre_get_posts','lw_search_filter_pages');
function lw_search_filter_pages($query) {
// Frontend search only
if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_search() ) {
    $query->set('post_type', 'product');
    $query->set( 'wc_query', 'product_query' );
}
return $query;
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish, since we have a blog on our page, that when a searchquery is fired from the /blog page or blogposts, that the normal blog search is used.

I've tried to add the if statement:

```
//Only show products in the front-end search results
function lw_search_filter_pages($query) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_search() ) {
        if($wp_query->query['pagename']=='blog'){
        }
        else {
        $query->set('post_type', 'product');
        $query->set( 'wc_query', 'product_query' );
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Without success. How do i proplery add the IF-Statement for blogpage & blogposts only? I've tried to add an if statement to the query if its not the pagename blog (though here we would miss the posts.

Comment: Also tried it with if ( ! is_home() ) { , but that didn't work out either

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand, but:

```
function lw_search_filter_pages ( $query ) {

    // ...

}

if ( is_front_page () || is_home () ) {} else {

    add_filter ( 'pre_get_posts', 'lw_search_filter_pages' );

}
```

Another:

```
function lw_search_filter_pages ( $query ) {

    // ...

}
                                   // https://yoursite.tld/blog
$uri = $_SERVER [ 'REQUEST_URI' ]; //             $uri = '/blog';

if ( $uri == '/blog' ) {} else {

    add_filter ( 'pre_get_posts', 'lw_search_filter_pages' );

}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this